# Apache NIFI: Recovering from Flowfile repository issue

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently trying to recover my flows from the below exception.

> failed to process session due to Cannot update journal file
>   /data/disk1/nifi/flowfile_repository/journals/90620570.journal because
>   no header has been written yet.; Processor Administratively Yielded
>   for 1 sec: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot update journal file
>   /data/disk1/nifi/flowfile_repository/journals/90620570.journal because
>   no header has been written yet.

I have seen some answers on best practices wrt to handling large files in Nifi, but my question is more about how to recover from this exception. My observation is that, once the exception is seen, it begins to appear in several processors in all the flows in our nifi instance, how do we recover without a restart?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your disk is full which is not allowing the processors to update or modify the data.

You can either increase your disk or you can delete the contents from your nifi repository.

first, check the logs folder. If its the logs folder thats taking up the space, you can directly do a

```
rm -rf logs/*
```

else just delete all the content

```
rm -rf logs/* content_repository/* provenance_repository/* flowfile_repository/* database_repository/*
```

PS : The deletion of the content will cause all your data on the canvas also to be deleted, so make sure you're not deleting the data which can't be reproduced.

Most likely, it must be the logs which must be eating up the space. Also, check your log rotation interval!

Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We did check the logs and disks for the repositories. Everything looked fine.

In the end, just did a restart. :)